# Multi-Tenant App - Getting Username for Users from Pivot Table

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I'm developing a multi-tenant application with single database approach. Each query is typically scoped by `subdomain_id`.

My database is structured as follows -

`users` : This table is shared by multiple tenants

```
id | first_name | last_name | created_at | updated_at
```

`subdomains`:

```
id | creator_id | name | slug | created_at | updated_at
```

`subdomains_users`: This is my pivot table

```
id | subdomain_id | user_id | username | created_at | updated_at
```

The relationships are defined as follows-

User:

```
public function subdomains(): BelongsToMany
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Subdomain::class, 'subdomains_users', 'creator_id', 'subdomain_id')->withPivot(['username'])->as('info')->using(SubdomainsUsers::class);
    }
```

Subdomain:

```
public function users(): BelongsToMany
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(User::class, 'subdomains_users', 'subdomain_id', 'owner_id')->withPivot(['username'])->as('info')->using(SubdomainsUsers::class);
    }
```

Throughout my application, I'm required to access the `username` attribute. However, as you can see, this isn't straightforward; because a user can belong to multiple subdomains.

How do I go about retrieving the `username` of any user for the current `subdomain`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like so:

in User model (assuming you have the current subdomain id in the session, or just replace it with what is appropriate for you):

```
public function getUsernameAttribute()
{
    return $this->subdomains
        ->first(fn($subdomain) => $subdomain->id == session('subdomain_id')) 
        ->pivot
        ->username;
}
```

and you'll be able to call `$user->username` to get the username for the current subdomain

Comment: I ended taking up a different approach. I now added a subdomain_id table on the User table; it makes things super straightforward.